# Shapes mismatch in Tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I wrote the following model fn:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout, Input, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import tensorflow as tf

def get_model(num_features, output_size, output_bias=None):
    output_bias = tf.keras.initializers.Constant(output_bias)

    opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.0008)

    inputs = Input(shape=[None, num_features], dtype=tf.float32, ragged=True)
    layers = LSTM(32, activation='tanh')(
        inputs.to_tensor(), mask=tf.sequence_mask(inputs.row_lengths()))

    layers = BatchNormalization()(layers)
    layers = Dropout(0.05)(layers)

    layers = Dense(32, activation='relu')(layers)
    layers = BatchNormalization()(layers)
    layers = Dropout(0.05)(layers)

    layers = Dense(32, activation='relu')(layers)
    layers = BatchNormalization()(layers)
    layers = Dropout(0.05)(layers)

    layers = Dense(output_size, activation='sigmoid',
                         bias_initializer=output_bias)(layers)
    model = Model(inputs, layers)
    model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), optimizer=opt, metrics=[tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=2)])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

here is the model summary:

```
Model: "model_5"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_6 (InputLayer)            [(None, None, 11)]   0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input.row_lengths_5 (InstanceMe (None,)              0           input_6[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input.to_tensor_5 (InstanceMeth (None, None, 11)     0           input_6[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf.sequence_mask_5 (TFOpLambda) (None, None)         0           input.row_lengths_5[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_5 (LSTM)                   (None, 32)           5632        input.to_tensor_5[0][0]          
                                                                 tf.sequence_mask_5[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_15 (BatchNo (None, 32)           128         lstm_5[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_15 (Dropout)            (None, 32)           0           batch_normalization_15[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_15 (Dense)                (None, 32)           1056        dropout_15[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_16 (BatchNo (None, 32)           128         dense_15[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_16 (Dropout)            (None, 32)           0           batch_normalization_16[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_16 (Dense)                (None, 32)           1056        dropout_16[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_17 (BatchNo (None, 32)           128         dense_16[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_17 (Dropout)            (None, 32)           0           batch_normalization_17[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_17 (Dense)                (None, 1)            33          dropout_17[0][0]                 
==================================================================================================
Total params: 8,161
Trainable params: 7,969
Non-trainable params: 192
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

And here are the shapes of my data:

```
print(train_x.shape,train_y.shape)
print(val_x.shape,val_y.shape)

(52499, None, 11) (52499,)
(17500, None, 11) (17500,)
```

When trying to fit my model, I get the following error:

```
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=300, batch_size=500, validation_data=(val_x, val_y))

ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 2 and 1. Shapes are [2] and [1].
```

I can't understand what is wrong with the shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model seems fine. The problem is that you are running into an open [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/746) with the `tfa.metrics.F1Score`. For your binary case, you will have to change the parameters of the F1Score to `tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=1, threshold=0.5)`. Here is a complete working example:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout, Input, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import tensorflow as tf

def get_model(num_features, output_size, output_bias=0.001):
    output_bias = tf.keras.initializers.Constant(output_bias)

    opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.0008)

    inputs = Input(shape=[None, num_features], dtype=tf.float32, ragged=True)
    layers = LSTM(32, activation='tanh')(
        inputs.to_tensor(), mask=tf.sequence_mask(inputs.row_lengths()))

    layers = BatchNormalization()(layers)
    layers = Dropout(0.05)(layers)

    layers = Dense(32, activation='relu')(layers)
    layers = BatchNormalization()(layers)
    layers = Dropout(0.05)(layers)

    layers = Dense(32, activation='relu')(layers)
    layers = BatchNormalization()(layers)
    layers = Dropout(0.05)(layers)

    layers = Dense(output_size, activation='sigmoid',
                         bias_initializer=output_bias)(layers)
    model = Model(inputs, layers)
    model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), optimizer=opt, metrics=[tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=1, threshold=0.5)])
    model.summary()
    return model


model = get_model(11, 1)
rt = tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_splits(values=tf.ones([5, 11], tf.int32),
                                  row_splits=[0, 2, 5])
model.fit(rt, tf.random.uniform((2,1), maxval=2), epochs=300, batch_size=2, verbose=2)
```

Alternatively, you just define your own F1Score method and set it as metric in your model. See this [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/45165/how-to-get-accuracy-f1-precision-and-recall-for-a-keras-model) for more information.